# Programmatical "Back" in Backbone.js

Tags: backbone.js, browser-history

I have a list of items in `#/xxx` which when clicked will pop up a lightbox and change the hash to `#/xxx/yyy`. In the lightbox, there's a "Back" button. How do I revert to previous page (i.e. "`#/xxx`")? I'm looking for something like "`Backbone.back()`". This action must not trigger the route handler (otherwise the list of items will be empty since it's an Ajax search result).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's two easy ways I can think of doing this:

1) Make the "back" button not really go back at all, just repeat the previous route (the one prior to bringing up the lightbox) again. Then going backwards and forwards through the history will produce the results you expect to see.

2) Just tell the browser to step back one step within the history. You can do that in JavaScript like so:

```
window.history.back();
```

Results should be just like the other way of doing the same thing.

Comment: 1st solution is not ideal since value must hardcoded (instead of "back to whatever page i was on"), but it works. 2nd solution doesn't work since it'll trigger the handler.

Comment: That's very true, the handler will be triggered, which will probably ask the model to fetch again or call a function on the model to perform the search again. I'm unclear why your search results would be empty though. I just finished doing something just like this and the popup did show details and going back triggered the route. However, it was trivial to tell the model to not re-perform the same search it already had results for and the view simply re-rendered what was already in the model.

Comment: I'm using Twitter-style pagination/scrolling for the search result. Let's say a user is in 'page 2' of search result, clicks link which opens detail page, then goes back to search result.

Comment: Perfect! There's no reason at all to throw away your search results just because you did that. Think of something like GMail, they have an index full of emails that you've received recently. You can drill down onto one of them and then come back out but the list is still in the model as well. They didn't discard it. How do I know? Try checking a few emails before you drill down. Now go back to the list and notice that the same selected emails are still selected now. They didn't throw away their data structures just because they got more detail on one particular email and displayed that.

Comment: this doesn't really cover it, for instance let's say that the lightbox is fired upon some particular route then you want to close and return - this would be fine if you navigated to the lightbox from the host site but what if you followed a direct link, win.his.back() would send you to another site rather than return you to the page